# Tools for Converting XML to C# Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I would like to know  whether any tool is avialable to convert an XML file to classes. I dont want to miss out the child nodes which will get converted into child classes. Please help me out for the same

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the xsd command-line utility that comes with .NET.

Comment: Do you need un deserialize XML to object c# or to dynamically generate .cs files from XML files ?

Comment: Needto create .cs files from XML file

Comment: Try this tool https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you have the **XML** string serialisation of an object you need to :

**1. generate an XML Schema from the XML object**

**2. generate a .cs file from the XML Schema**

"I dont want to miss out the child nodes which will get converted into child classes." -- It all depends on the **XML** Schema generated from the **XML** string.

You can try:

1. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx)